# Alternative to synchronized for 100% race free code in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithread programs and to java and I was wondering if there is any way to use locks instead of synchronize for a small program and achieve a better performance.

So far I tried to use readWriteLock to lock when reading and lock when writing but it seems to work slower than the synchronized version.

Comment: `synchronized` _is_ locking.  It's locking wrapped up in syntax that somewhat limits your ability to mis-use it by somewhat limiting its power.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the best performance will come from the strategy that minimizes the time that threads must sit idle while waiting for other threads to complete.  But which strategy achieves that goal depends on what logic you are trying to make thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Locks may be more useful for more complicated things where you can't acquire and release in such a clean manner. I would honestly prefer to avoid using bare Locks in the first place, and just go with a more sophisticated concurrency control such as a CyclicBarrier or a LinkedBlockingQueue, if they meet your needs.

```
synchronized(myObject)
   {
        doSomethingNifty();
   }
```

I prefer to use Syncronized than locks because it is impossible to do wrong when using Syncronized .

Comment: There is still *a lot* you can do wrong with `synchronized`…

Comment: Synchronized is my preferred method as well, but after presenting my project, I was asked to get rid of synchronized and use locks instead.